# Regex to grab data from massive HTML string

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am grabbing a HTML source dump that includes some sort of JSON props created by react.

Trying to grab data in syntax like this: `"siteName":"Example Site"`. I want to grab that "Example Site" text without the quotations.

I know I could be using an HTML parser but this is actually within some JS code in the source.

Any thoughts on how I could do this? Thanks

Comment: Show us some complete date if you can.  I presume it would be HTML which in turn has some JSON content inside it.

Comment: Something like this: `{"siteName":"ABC Example Business","contactName":"Jeff","siteKey":"abcexample","tabKey":"service","entityKey":"1192289","siteId":152285976,"entityId":13123055221,"phone":"","mobile":"0100 000 000", etc etc` And that is all buried in hundreds of lines of other JS stuff. Within a `<script>` tag.

Comment: If you already have this text isolated, then you should _absolutely_ be using a JSON parser here.  Regex very bad for JSON.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you mean by isolated? I essentially the whole HTML page source in a string, thats it. (Struggling, sorry not very knowledgeable with this)

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that once you have that JSON text in a variable, then use a JSON parser.  Maybe you need some XPath first to get that JSON, I really don't know.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I could give that a go.

Comment: It's bad idea to use regex to parse HTML/JSON... Use CSS selector/XPath along with appropriate tool for parsing HTML and JSON parser

Answer (score 1):

With this regex you get it but I would use something else like a Json parser

```js
var regex = /"siteName":"(.+?)"/g;
var str = `{"siteName":"ABC Example Business","contactName":"Jeff","siteKey":"abcexample","tabKey":"service","entityKey":"1192289","siteId":152285976,"entityId":13123055221,"phone":"","mobile":"0100 000 000",}`;

var result = regex.exec(str);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Comment: Beautiful. Now these things are buried in hundreds of lines of code, is there perhaps a better way overall I could be finding this information?

Comment: @KriiV What you mean with "are buried in hundreds of lines of code"? you mean there are multiple `siteName` or is the file simply too big? Maybe could you post an example file or a part of it?

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

\"siteName\":\"(.+)\"